# Near "*": syntax error Unable to execute statement

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to execute an sqlite code that delete all values from the table 'Categories"

Here is My code:

```
function deleteCATs() {
    var db = LocalStorage.openDatabaseSync("Cat", "1.0", "Deleting Categories File", 1000000);

    db.transaction(
        function(tx) {
            tx.executeSql('DELETE * FROM Categories');
            //tx.executeSql('DELETE FROM Categories WHERE Category ="Cat"');
        }
    )
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
"Near "*": syntax error Unable to execute statement"
```

Any ideas on how this can be fixed? I'm using Qt Creator 3.0.0, Qt 5.2.0 Android version

Comment: Drop the `*`; you use `SELECT * FROM Categories`, but `DELETE FROM Categories` (assuming you want to delete all rows).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is:

```
DELETE FROM Categories;
```

(The `*` is not necessary.)

Or, better yet in almost any database other than SQLite:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE Categories;
```

Comment: According to https://www.sqlite.org/lang_delete.html , the * is not only not necessary, it's actually not allowed.